# jQuery Datatable search is not working while using autocomplete field populated data and dependent data

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

My page contains the first input text box is autocomplete field. Based on the selected value we are populating the remaining data normal text and input, select drop down values.

When I try to search the values using datatables search its not working for me.

Sample Screenshot for Datatable with search

[image]

my sample code used for adding dynamic row.

```
table.row.add(['<input type="text" id="field1" class="field1" name="field1" />',
    '<label id="field2" name="field2"></label>',
    '<input type="text" id="field3" name="field3" />',
    '<label id="field4" name="field4"></label>',
    '<input type="text" id="field5" name="field5" />',
    '<label id="field6" name="field6"></label>',
    '<input type="text"  id="field7" name="field7" />',
    '<select  id="field8" name="field8"></select>',
    '<select  id="field9" name="field9"></select>'
]).draw();
```

I try with below code changes but its not working for me.

- [search is not working in jquery datatables with dynamically populated table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753625/search-is-not-working-in-jquery-datatables-with-dynamically-populated-table)
- [JQuery Datatables search within input and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852497/jquery-datatables-search-within-input-and-select)

When i try with `table.cell($td).invalidate().draw()`. My autocomplete functionality is breaking.

Comment: Hi :) How about a working snippet or a fiddle? that could save us a lot of time... and questions !

Comment: I have added simple fiddle for dynamic data. With default value I am able to search. After change with dynamic value its not working for me.
https://jsfiddle.net/kaarthikmail/q4b7gpoj/8/

Comment: Hi I think draw.dt is not firing

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a snippet or a fiddle ? There is already a difference btw the fiddle and here, then Populate it with a dummy data using a static json Object like the one you are getting in your project!